# What AWS component can be used to batch the requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a case, where I am receiving some message from SNS to AWS Lambda function. In this lambda function, I am transforming the message and then pushing it to Dynamo Db. But if I directly pushing it to Dynamo Db, then it may throttle Dynamo Db. So, I wanted to batch the incoming requests and then push it to Dynamo Db. As far as I know, batching can't be done in AWS Lambda as it is stateless. So, can someone give some suggestions, what can I use after AWS Lambda in which I can batch requests? Or if there is any way I can do it in AWS Lambda itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I would do is:

- SNS -> Lambda -> SQS
- OnDemand Lambda (SQS -> DynamoDB)

Since SQS cannot trigger Lambda, schedule Lambda periodically to read from SQS and push it to DynamoDB.

Comment: Or a slight variation: Lambda pushes to DynamoDB, but if it is rejected due to bandwidth throttling, then put it in SQS for later (timed) processing. This way, DynamoDB throughput can be based on *average* throughput rather than *peak* throughput.